TesseractOCR fails to load images – getting the following error: Failed to load image from file
Please could someone tell me what am i doing wrong?
The line that errors:
using (var img = TesseractOCR.Pix.Image.LoadFromFile(imagePath))

Steps taken to create the application:

The application is created using the .Net Framework 4.8 C#
Installed TesseractOCR using NuGet
Added tessdata from here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata into the project folder
Added the following code:

    public class OCRTest
    {
        public static string PerformOCR(string imagePath)
        {
            
            try
            {
                string tessDataPath = @"C:\Repos\OCR\Tesseract-OCR2\tessdata";

                using (var engine = new Engine(tessDataPath, Language.English, EngineMode.Default))
                {
                    using (var img = TesseractOCR.Pix.Image.LoadFromFile(imagePath))
                    {
                        using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                        {
                            return page.Text;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

private void btnOCR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string imagePath = @"C:\TestImages\20230820_210122.jpg";

            if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File doesnt exist: {imagePath}");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                string recognizedText = OCRTest.PerformOCR(imagePath);
                if (recognizedText != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Recognized text:\n" + recognizedText, "OCR Result");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No text recognized.", "OCR Result");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "OCR Error");
            }
        }


I've just tried with a tif file and that has worked okay. So the issue was probably with the jpg file that i originally tried.

It seems to work for me. Perhaps create a new image. Type some text in Notepad, Wordpad, Word, etc... Then use the Windows Snipping Tool to take a screen shot of the text and save it.
